# Need help making a discord music bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a music bot, and, im struggling with some parts. I don't know how to make the skip part or play the next song in the queue once the current one ends. Any help?
Here is all the code (all of it because just in case)

The queue part is near the bottom, the skip part is also near the bottom and playing the song is right below here.

````
import os
import re
import urllib.request
import youtube_dl
import shutil
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='g.')
token = '<mytoken>'

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, *args: str):
    search = '+'.join(args)
    print(search)
    if search == " ":
        await ctx.send("Uso: g.play (Video)")
        return
    else:
        html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search)
        video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0]
        print(url)

        def check_queue():
            Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
            if Queue_infile is True:
                DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
                length = len(os.listdir(DIR))
                still_q = length - 1
                try:
                    first_file = os.listdir(DIR)[0]
                except:
                    print("No more queued song(s)\n")
                    queues.clear()
                    return
                main_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
                song_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + "\\" + first_file)
                if length != 0:
                    print("Song done, playing next queued\n")
                    print(f"Songs still in queue: {still_q}")
                    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
                    if song_there:
                        os.remove("song.mp3")
                    shutil.move(song_path, main_location)
                    for file in os.listdir("./"):
                        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
                            enfile = file

                    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
                    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
                    voice.source.volume = 0.07
                    print(f"Playing {nname[0]}")

                else:
                    queues.clear()
                    return
            else:
                queues.clear()
                print("No songs were queued before the ending of the last song\n")

        song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
        try:
            if song_there:
                os.remove("song.mp3")
                queues.clear()
                print("Removed old song file")
        except PermissionError:
            print("Trying to delete song file, but it's being played.")
            print("ERROR: Music Playing")
            await ctx.send("Error: Ya estoy poniendo musica! Usa g.queue (cancion) para agregar una cancion a la lista.")
            search = ' '.join(args)
            channel = ctx.message.channel
            return

    Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
    try:
        Queue_folder = "./Queue"
        if Queue_infile is True:
            print("Removed old Queue Folder")
            shutil.rmtree(Queue_folder)
    except:
        print("No old queue folder.")

    print("Getting everytihng ready now.")
    await ctx.send("Preparando cancion...")

    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'quiet': True,
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',

        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print("Downloading audio now\n")
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            print(f"Renamed file: {file}\n")
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
            nfile = file

    print(str(voice))
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.3

    nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
    print(f"Playing {nname[0]}")
    await embed(ctx, url, nfile, video_ids[0])

queues = {}


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def queue(ctx, *searchs):
    search = '+'.join(searchs)
    Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
    if Queue_infile is False:
        os.mkdir("Queue")
    DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
    q_num = len(os.listdir(DIR))
    q_num += 1
    add_queue = True
    while add_queue:
        if q_num in queues:
            q_num += 1
        else:
            add_queue = False
            queues[q_num] = q_num

    queue_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + f"\song{q_num}.%(ext)s")

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'quiet': True,
        'outtmpl': queue_path,
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192'
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print("Downloading audio now\n")
        html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search)
        video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0]
        print(url)
        ydl.download([url])
    await ctx.send("Añadiendo cancion " + str(q_num) + " a la lista!")

    print("Song added to the queue:" + str(q_num))


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"""Bot {bot.user} has connected to discord!""")




bot.run(token)```
````

Comment: well then guess no one can help since it's on -3 votes :/

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605422/discord-py-music-bot-how-to-combine-a-play-and-queue-command/53617634#53617634) for a simple example of how to create a queue

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can get code for understanding its not the proper-one but it can help you.

[Music Bot Code](https://github.com/aamit2267/MusicBot)

You will get an idea how to code these commands.