# Unresolved attribute reference 'voice_client_in' for class 'Bot'

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a discord bot that can queue a song. I saw a code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605422/discord-py-music-bot-how-to-combine-a-play-and-queue-command) but the code showed an error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Komputer\PycharmProjects\CiaaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Komputer\PycharmProjects\CiaaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Komputer\PycharmProjects\CiaaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'is_voice_connected'
```

What should I do then?

Comment: Please show us your code in your question.

Comment: The code you are looking at is quite outdated, nowadays discord.py does not include `is_voice_connected`, you should at some other example or try to achieve it yourself through the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_voice_connected` is outdated

You should use `Guild.voice_client`

```py
@bot.command()
async def queue(ctx):
    if ctx.guild.voice_client: # Its connected to voice
        ...
```