# How to make discord bot say what song is being played next

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my discord bot able to say a message when a new song is played that was in the queue.

For example,

[image]

So basically when a song ends and it plays the next, it would say something similar above. I was thinking I can write this in my play command. My current code for my play command is

```py
@commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        invc = ctx.author.voice
        botinvc = ctx.guild.me.voice
        if not invc:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, You are not in a VC!')
            return
        if invc:
            if not botinvc:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
                player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
                if not player:
                    player =  music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=True)
                if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
                    await player.queue(url, search=True)
                    song = await player.play()
                    await ctx.send(f'Now Playing: `{song.name}`')
            
            if botinvc:
                player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
                if not player:
                    player =  music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=True)
                if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
                    await player.queue(url, search=True)
                    song = await player.play()
                    await ctx.send(f'Now Playing: `{song.name}`')
                else:
                    song = await player.queue(url, search=True)
                    embed=discord.Embed(title='Song Added to Queue!', description=f'**{song.name}** added!', color=0x00FFFF)
                    author = ctx.message.author
                    pfp = author.avatar_url
                    embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author.name}", icon_url=pfp)
                    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                    embed.set_footer(text=f'Added by {ctx.author}')
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

my imports are,

```py
import discord
import datetime
import DiscordUtils
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
```

How could I get this to function? I am using the DiscordUtils library for this.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605422/discord-py-music-bot-how-to-combine-a-play-and-queue-command) help you?

Comment: @Guddi That code is outdated. Also, I already have my queue system worked out. Just whenever the next song is played that was in the queue, it would say like, "Now playing: {song}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi have you tried using `after`.

`song = await player.play(after=send_message_function)`

You can create a raw queue list and pop songs that have been played and get the function to return the first song in the list.
Something like

```
async def send_message_function():
    queue.pop(0)
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Now Playing: {queue[0]}"))
```

Comment: How can I define `queue`? Right now, it is undefined

Comment: I also get this error.. `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: play() got an unexpected keyword argument 'after'`

Comment: @ColeTMK [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-in-python/) is how you can create a queue in python